# How can I use descriptors for non-static methods?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am aware that I can use descriptors to change static property as if it were a normal property. However, when I try using descriptors for a normal class property, I end up changing the object it references to, instead of the value in the object.

If I have

Normal use, considering that the method(param) returns an object

```
class SomeClass():
    property = method(param)
```

I can then do:

```
instance = SomeClass()
instance.property = 3
```

and be able to have that setting handled by the the class of which property is an instance.

Now, if I instead have

```
class SomeClass():
    def__init__(self):
        self.property = method(param)
```

and I do:

```
instance = SomeClass()
instance.property = 3
```

That code does not work, and I overwrite the reference to the object created by method(param) with 3, instead of having that setting handled by the descriptor.

Is there a way I can use descriptors without static methods? In essence, I need to be able to create several instances of the class, each with its own unique properties that can be altered using the convenient descriptor method. Is that possible?

Python version: 2.7

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `method(param)` returns a descriptor, you may invoke it manually with a property like so:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._descriptor = method(param)

    @property
    def my_attribute(self):
        return self._descriptor.__get__(self, self.__class__)

    @my_attribute.setter
    def my_attribute(self, value):
        self._descriptor.__set__(self, value)
```

This will allow you to create instance-specific descriptors instead of class-level descriptors.

I still do not see the reason for you to do that as descriptors should usuallty be class-level. That's their point. Else they are just regular objects which you can call using properties.

Comment: Basically, I am using selenium and page objects to model a page. The page object module is third-party and uses descriptors  with static properties(elements of the page as descriptors, with the user being able to insert text into a text box using `=` operator). But I need to be able instantiate more than one page object at the same time (2 browsers navigating the same page), with each having its own instances of the elements that comprise the page. So i need to make that adjustment in order to take advantage of a module that is already built.

Thanks, I will try your code later today

Answer (score 1):

Descriptors provide a simple mechanism for variations on the usual patterns of binding functions into methods.

To recap, functions have a `__get__()` method so that they can be converted to a method when accessed as attributes. The non-data descriptor transforms an `obj.f(*args)` call into `f(obj, *args)`. Calling `klass.f(*args)` becomes `f(*args)`.

This chart summarizes the binding and its two most useful variants:

```
Transformation  Called from an Object   Called from a Class
function            f(obj, *args)           f(*args)
staticmethod        f(*args)                f(*args)
classmethod         f(type(obj), *args)     f(klass, *args)
```

Static methods return the underlying function without changes. Calling either c.f or C.f is the equivalent of a direct lookup into

`object.__getattribute__(c, "f") or object.__getattribute__(C, "f").`
   As a result, the function becomes identically accessible from either an object or a class.

Good candidates for static methods are methods that do not reference the self variable.

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    """A data descriptor that sets and returns values
       normally and prints a message logging their access.
    """
    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print 'Retrieving', self.name
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print 'Updating', self.name
        self.val = val

>>> class MyClass(object):
...     x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')
...     y = 5
...
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.x
Retrieving var "x"
10
>>> m.x = 20
Updating var "x"
>>> m.x
Retrieving var "x"
20
>>> m.y
5
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand this application that you demonstrated. I just wondered if, for instance, x and y (in your code) could be properties of the object (accessible through self.<variable name>), instead of static variables of the class. What do you say?

Answer (score 0):

Properties are "computed attributes". Properties are implemented using descriptors. If an object's attribute is looked up and a descriptor object is found, the descriptor's getter function will compute the value.

**This special rule is valid only at the class level**.

That's why:

```
class SomeClass():
    property = <a property object here>
```

defines a property (computed attribute) for all `SomeClass` instances, but:

```
class SomeClass():
    def__init__(self):
        self.property = <a property object here>
```

defines an ordinary attribute which happens to be of property object type, but is not treated specially in any way. Its getters and setters are ignored (unless called explicitely by the user code, of course).

---

There is no other way of using descriptors and properties as setting them in the class and not in an instance.

UPDATE - Example:

Small example: instead of creating several instances each with its own descriptor (approach which does not work), a new subclass is instantiated every time.

```
class BaseClass:
    pass

_class_number = 0 
def class_factory(prop):
    global _class_number
    _class_number += 1
    return type('Class' + str(_class_number), (BaseClass,), dict(prop=prop))

c1 = class_factory(property(fget=lambda self: "property1"))()
print(c1.prop)
c2 = class_factory(property(fget=lambda self: "property2"))()
print(c2.prop)
```

Answer (score 0):

guys,

Thanks for the help. Out of many great suggestions, I decided to wrap the **set** and **get** methods, thus losing the practicality of descriptors, while keeping the practicality of having a module completely programmed for me. I simply extended the class "PageElement" and created two new methods get() and set(), which call their correspondent implementations:

```
def get(self):
    return self.__get__(self.owner_page, self.owner_page.__class__)

def set(self, value):
    self.__set__(self.owner_page, value)
```

Thanks for the help! I opened up my eyes to a lot of details in the language that I still do not know. And I will keep digging.