# How to use descriptor (or something similar) in Python for non-static fields without loosing the encapsulation?

Tags: python, properties, static-methods, encapsulation, descriptor

Actually my question was already discussed previously here:
[How can I use descriptors for non-static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667904/how-can-i-use-descriptors-for-non-static-methods)

And there were some nice ways of doing it, naming 3 of them specifically:

1. Use properties and define getter and setter separately (*Accepted solution but it looses the encapsulation*)
2. Use a ClassFactory to create separate classes just to make the static fields separate (*Nice workaround but not a real solution*)
3. Ignore the descriptor and properties features and just use set and get function normally. (*Final chosen solution by the person who initiated the question, just because it is the easiest, I think!*)

All of the above solutions work well but to me none of them are complete. You can see my comments for each offered solution in the brackets.

Now I would like to ask the same question again but this time considering this specific use-case:

I am creating some helpers for the other developers and I would like to hide (encapsulate) all the redundant stuff in the helper classes and just make it easy for using it for the other developers, which might not know anything about the properties.

This is an example which I would like the developers to use:

```
class TestStruct(BaseStruct):
    # define structure
    field1 = SomeField()
    field2 = OtherField()
    field3 = NextField()
```

BaseStruct and SomeField/OtherField/ThirdField are as part of the helper classes and other developers don't see them but just using them.

Then they can focus on the structure definition instead of defining properties and so on and they will just use the fields like:

```
my_struct = TestStruct()
my_struct.field1 = SOME_VALUE
...
```

But the problem is the fields are defined as static members, which we know all the down-parts of static fields in this case.

So the question is how can I have them non-static and still keep the structure in the TestStruct simple by moving all the complexity of defining properties (or anything else) into the BaseStruct.

Note that the fields are defined by other developers and we don't know about them.

Any suggestions in Python 2 or 3 are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `we know all the down-parts of static fields in this case`? Why are you hunger for properties/descriptors? Why don't you just create a normal class and then use it in a common way like creating objects of it? Documentation and examples are much more useful than additional layers of abstraction and/or simplification.

Comment: "we know all the down-parts of static fields in this case"
    You can instantiate only one object and then cannot work with more than one at the same time, because the static fields are shared!

Comment: Regarding "Why don't you just create a normal class and then use it in a common way ...": Yes it is another solution but just thinking to make it simpler for the users and also considering the fact "There is nothing I cannot do" ;)